# Remove one element from each row of a matrix, each in a different column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

How can I remove elements in a matrix, that aren't all in a straight line, without going through a row at a time in a for loop?

Example:

```
[1 7 3 4;
 1 4 4 6;
 2 7 8 9]
```

Given a vector (e.g. [2,4,3]) How could I remove the elements in each row  (where each number in the vector corresponds to the column number) without going through each row at a time and removing each element?

The example output would be:

```
[1 3 4;
 1 4 4;
 2 7 9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) at follows. Note that it's better to work down columns (because of Matlab's [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) order), which implies transposing at the beginning and at the end:

```
A = [ 1 7 3 4
      1 4 4 6
      2 7 8 9 ];
v = [2 4 3]; %// the number of elements of v must equal the number of rows of A
B = A.'; %'// transpose to work down columns
[m, n] = size(B);
ind = v + (0:n-1)*m; %// linear index of elements to be removed
B(ind) = []; %// remove those elements. Returns a vector
B = reshape(B, m-1, []).'; %'// reshape that vector into a matrix, and transpose back
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you get this to work for a 3D matrix (where all the layers in the element are deleted?). Or would linear indexing for a 3D matrix be too unwieldy?

Comment: I think it can be done. But i'm not sure that you want. Since this seems to be a significant change from the original question, I suggest you post a new one. Be sure to include an example

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to solve for a 3D array case, assuming you want to remove indexed elements per row across all 3D slices  -

```
%// Inputs
A = randi(9,3,4,3)
idx = [2 4 3]

%// Get size of input array, A
[M,N,P] = size(A)

%// Permute A to bring the columns as the first dimension
Ap = permute(A,[2 1 3])

%// Per 3D slice offset linear indices
offset = bsxfun(@plus,[0:M-1]'*N,[0:P-1]*M*N)  %//'

%// Get 3D array linear indices and remove those from permuted array
Ap(bsxfun(@plus,idx(:),offset)) = []

%// Permute back to get the desired output
out = permute(reshape(Ap,3,3,3),[2 1 3])
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A(:,:,1) =
     4     4     1     4
     2     9     7     5
     5     9     3     9
A(:,:,2) =
     4     7     7     2
     9     6     6     9
     3     5     2     2
A(:,:,3) =
     1     7     5     8
     6     2     9     6
     8     4     2     4
>> out
out(:,:,1) =
     4     1     4
     2     9     7
     5     9     9
out(:,:,2) =
     4     7     2
     9     6     6
     3     5     2
out(:,:,3) =
     1     5     8
     6     2     9
     8     4     4
```